# DocuSign - Attach Completed Documents to Salesforce Object

Tags: rest, salesforce, docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I'm trying to attach a completed docusign document to a custom object (Compliance_Item__c) either under the notes and attachments or files related list in salesforce. I'm thinking it's an issue with my request but I'm unsure as to what needs to be changed to properly pass in the custom object's record id.

This is the request I am making to Docusign to create the envelope via REST Api.

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [
          {
            "name": "Compliance_Item__c",
            "value": "' + complianceItem.Id + '",
            "configurationType": "salesforce"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "clientUserId": 1,
      "roleName": "Signer 1",
      "name": "' + contact.Name + '",
      "email": "' + contact.Email + '",
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "SignerCompany",
            "xPosition": "104",
            "yPosition": "174",
            "name": "SignerCompany",
            "value": "' + contact.Company_Name__c + '"
          },
          {
            "tabLabel": "SignerTitle",
            "xPosition": "104",
            "yPosition": "202",
            "name": "SignerTitle",
            "value": "' + contact.Title + '"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "returnUrl": "https://demo.docusign.net",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "userName": "WW Vendor",
  "emailSubject": "Please DocuSign Test Document",
  "templateId": "' + templateId + '"
}
```

Here's an image of the docusign settings for connecting to my salesforce custom object.

[Docusign Salesforce Connect Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR3YQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

We don’t have a good recipe for this specific use case, but the [PowerForm write-back process](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-configure-a-PowerForm-to-writeback-to-specific-Salesforce-records) is fairly similar. The only real difference is that they would be attaching the envelope instead of updating fields.
You may also want to reach out to your DocuSign representative if you need additional functionality.